# Chrome Extensions - make a cross domain AJAX request

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, jsonp

I working on experimental learn-by-doing project.
My chrome extensions (loading unpacked locally) has some AJAX calls (cross domain, JSONP)

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

`Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:3318/servicestack.ashx/api/?callback=cb&ActionName=DoStuff&_=1370346168979' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' http://localhost".`

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Testing Chrome",
  "description": "Test test test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions" : [  
    "http://localhost/"   
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost; object-src 'self'"
  }
```

Any suggestions on what is wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

> The restriction against resources loaded over HTTP applies only to
>   those resources which are directly executed.

Is the script directly executed or do you have **JSONP** mechanism?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Not sure what you mean by directly executed, the ajax calls return JSON data.

Comment: @User789: Could you please provide me sample output it returns?

Comment: Problem solved. I had to add the port number `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost:3318; object-src 'self'"`

Comment: example JSON returned: `cb({"0":{"Error":"Wrong Password Or Username!"}})`